# Use one Mongo doc to hold thousands of objects, or thousands of docs each holding one?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs

In my web app, an authenticated user can pick songs from his spotify playlist to play at a party. I want guests (nonauthenticated users) to be able to view the picked songs on a dynamically created react route and vote on their favorite songs on their own device (probably a phone).

I am using a Mongo, Express, React/Redux, Node stack.

Since the guests don't have access to my app's redux store, the only way they can view the authenticated user's picked songs is through a GET request to my app's database. My initial plan was to just store playlist documents, and the users can GET those playlists to make a request to the spotify api. However, they are unauthorized and need an access token. This means that my database has to store every single one of the songs that the authenticated user picked.

My question has to do with design. I don't think it's a good idea for my one document to hold every song because some people might want to pick thousands of songs, and one document won't be able to hold all of the songs. On the other hand, creating a separate document for each song seems a little bit too excessive.

Can anyone help me figure out which option is better, or if there is a different option I haven't thought of that can avoid this problem altogether? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that if you would store each song in a separated document, the main disadvantage of this strategy is the space complexity, you'll need more space to store all documents.

But, supposing you'll keep all song documents at the same collection, it gives some advantages, for example: queries and sorts operations will be more flexible and faster. It helps you to save both processing and development time. A similar logic is showed [here](http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents/).

Use just one document to store all songs makes your database operations more complex, what requires more development time and code to organize all retrieved data on the proper way. Another disadvantage is that it isn't a long term scalable strategy, [mainly because the limit of a BSON document is 16MB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size).

At my vision, the design of separated documents for each song is more appropriate and the reasons are:

1. Space is monetarily cheap.
2. Save time complexity must be a priority on all points of software development. Database queries usually are the slower operations in a software. So, reduce the cost of time at database operations is a good objective to seek. Storing all documents in one collection instead of in one document will retrieve all data already organized, with no no need to retreat at code.